# How to use NSDateTimeFormatter to convert this string to UnixTime?

Tags: cocoa, time, formatting, format, datetime-format

Here is the time string :

```
30 MAR 2011 10:14:28
```

And I would like to convert it to the time in millisecond since 1970. How can I do so? Thank you.

Comment: That's a lot of milliseconds!

Answer (score 3):

The class is NSDateFormatter, not NSDateTimeFormatter. You would first initialize the formatter with the [appropriate format](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns), something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Then use it to parse the date string:

```
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:string];
```

Then you can easily get a `double` representing seconds since 1970 from the date:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

And then multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.

Comment: Hey, you should accept this answer. Anomie went through the trouble of helping you and this a good answer!

Comment: @Alec: if you comment on Anomie's answer, the person who posted the question doesn't get notified of your comment.

Comment: Haha, it's not that important anyways. I just am bummed out when people make an account to ask a single question and then don't accept answers. No more vigilante though, people seem to agree that I am just being annoying :P